# Display japanse url image with nginx

Tags: image, nginx, cjk

I have uploaded to image to server and keep the name as japanese like (ヒラkがな.jpg)

https://img.smartmat.jp/5000020/img/SS00000000006%E3%83%92%E3%83%A9k%E3%81%8B%E3%82%99%E3%81%AA.jpg

But image is not displayed, for english name is fine.

[image]

How to display the image with Japanese name?

What should i fix the issue? is issue from nginx config or need to encode file name to readable?

any suggestions will be appreciate.

[Update]

as suggestion  Ullaakut
just add `.*UTF8` to location config 
like `location ~ /(.*UTF8)$ {`
you can refer in config file 
https://gist.github.com/thanhtungka91/9ea3623d84bb0ec4cf22723896419a3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be using the Windows version of Nginx? Apparently there is an issue with unicode characters, and a workaround can be found [here](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,224105,224201#msg-224201) if that's the case.

Comment: it is linux but add "utf-8" on location and it works fine!!! 
ex: location ~ /(.*UTF8)$ {

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help even if it wasn't exactly the issue that I suspected initially, haha.

Comment: How would you change this to work in a subfolder?